# Passing copy-of to a function?

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to select a copy of the following nodes:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="node1/node2/*" />
```

and I need to pass the value of this copy into a function ProcessNodes that receives a string as input parameter and return a string to do some processing, and write the result as:

```
<Data>
   Result of the function
</Data>
```

I thought I can put

```
<Data>
    <xsl:copy-of select="myfunction:ProcessNodes(node1/node2/*)" />
</Data>
```

but this is incorrect.

May I know the correct syntax to do this?

**PS**: Actually the document is a XML which is something like:

```
<Node1>
    <Node2>
       <html>
          <body>
              <p>My first paragraph.</p>
              <p>My 2nd paragraph. And this paragrah
                 has 2 lines.</p>
          </body>
       </html> 
    </Node2>
</Node1>
```

and I need to write them as

```
<Data>
    My first paragraph.
    My 2nd paragraph. And this paragrah has 2 lines.
</Data>
```

Note that the 2 lines in the 2nd paragraph are merged as 1 line.

That is why I need the copy-of so that the tags `<p>` can be preserved and I can do the arrangement of the paragraph I want.

I do not know if there is something easier.

Comment: shouldn't you be using value-of in there:  
<Data>
    <xsl:value-of select="myfunction:ProcessNodes(node1/node2/*)" />
</Data>

Comment: Thanks Michiel. I need to preserve the tags in the node that is why I must use copy-of.

Comment: Have you tried `<xsl:variable name="x"><xsl:copy-of .. /></xsl:variable><xsl:value-of select="myfunction:ProcessNodes($x)" />`?

Comment: So, what is incorrect? What result do you get and why is it incorrect? What is the result you want produced? What is the source XML document? Severely underspecified!!!

Comment: @Dimitre: I think the OP is referring to the error returned by the pocessor when passing a sequence of nodes to the function input.

Comment: @Dimitre: Thanks. I added PS at the bottom of my question to elaborate a bit more of my issue.

Comment: @Steven the PS at the bottom of your question is still not clear I think. I've extended my answer, may be it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not pass the sequence of nodes. Just pass the parent element then use it inside the function scope to get the children.

```
<xsl:value-of select="myfunction:ProcessNodes(node1/node2)" />
```

---

After having added your "PS", your intent is still unclear (to me at least). The result you want can be achieved without any cutom function. For example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*/*/*/*">
        <Data>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="p"/>
        </Data>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(normalize-space(.),'&#xA;')"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You are awesome! That's exactly what I want but being new to XSLT I couldn't think of an easier way! Thanks again.

Comment: You are welcome! For curiosity, have you accepted the first part of answer or the second one?

Comment: 2nd one empo. I still can't get 1st part working for me. What I was thinking initially is to get the string <body><p>My first paragraph.</p><p>My 2nd paragraph. And this paragraph has 2 lines.</p></body> and split by looking at the <p> them in my C# function. Hence I need to pass the body with the tags preserved, and I thought passing copy-of into the function would do the trick. I am still keen in knowing that, if that is even possible.

Answer (score 2):

Why does the function need a copy of the nodes? Why can't it work with the original?

If you do need this you can make the copy in a variable and pass the variable to the function call - but I find it hard to see why the copying should be needed, unless perhaps it's an extension function with side-effects.

Comment: I think the OP is referring to the error returned by the pocessor when passing a sequence of nodes to the function input.

Comment: @Michael: Thanks. I added PS at the bottom of my question to elaborate a bit more of my issue.